# listview with multi-selection in monodroid

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android

How to create a `ListView` in mono for android with multi-selection. Please help with some source example.

In java it is `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

I can't find something like that for mono for android.

Using: list.ChoiceMode = (int)ChoiceMode.Multiple;

checkboxes for raws selections didn't shows

Comment: can you post your code ? then tell what you do?

Comment: ICursor namesCursor = ManagedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri, null, null, null, null);
            StartManagingCursor(namesCursor);
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapt = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.test, namesCursor, new string[] { ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.DisplayName }, new int[] {Resource.Id.label});

            ListView list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.AddContactsListView);
            list.ChoiceMode = (int)ChoiceMode.Multiple;
            list.Adapter = adapt;

Comment: No I'm not. I'm using SimpleCursorAdapter with Resource.Layout.test where are only checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

That method is mapped to the [ChoiceMode](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.AbsListView.ChoiceMode) property in Mono for Android:

```
view.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
```